# find the coefficient of $x$ , in $P_{20}(x)$

Tags: combinatorics

Let $P_0(x) = x^3 + 313x^2 - 77x - 8$ , For integers $n \ge 1$ , define $P_n(x) = P_{n - 1}(x - n)$ , How do I find the coefficient of $x$ , in $P_{20}(x)$ ?

Comment: You write down what $P_1$ is (but don't multiply it out). Then you write down what $P_2$ is, and what $P-3$ is, and so on, until you see a pattern. Then, you'll know what $P_{20}$ is, and then you'll be able to find the coefficient of $x$. Well, it's worth a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It follows from the definition of $P_n$ that
$$ P_n(x) = P_0\left(x - \frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right) $$

Therefore,
$$ P_{20}(x) = P_{0}(x - 210) = (x - 210)^3 + 313 (x - 210)^2 - 77 (x - 210) - 8 $$
and therefore the coefficient of $x$ must be
$$ 3 \cdot 210^2 - 313 \cdot 2 \cdot 210 - 77 = 763 $$

Comment: So, you've destroyed any chance OP had of feeling the joy of solving the problem.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Should I hide it?

Comment: @YagnaPatel. It is too late already. But next time, better give a hint.

Comment: @wythagoras Is it a good answer though?

Comment: Well, the solution is correct, if you mean that.